# How to avoid meson error when installing gtksourceview4 4.4.0-1

Tags: software-installation

I am attempting to install gtksourceview4 4.4.0-1 on Ubuntu 18.04 using meson 4.5

I am following the instructions in README, having already created the directory build:

```
Installation
------------

Simple install procedure from a tarball:

  $ mkdir build
  $ meson build
```

I get the error:

```
jeff@snowdon:~/Programs/gtksourceview-4.4.0$ meson build
The Meson build system
Version: 0.52.1
Source dir: /home/jeff/Programs/gtksourceview-4.4.0
Build dir: /home/jeff/Programs/gtksourceview-4.4.0/build
Build type: native build

meson.build:1:6: ERROR: Expecting eof got id.
mkdir build
  ^
```

I have

```
jeff@snowdon:~/Programs/gtksourceview-4.4.0$ ls -l build
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 jeff jeff 4096 Dec 13 17:05 meson-info
drwxrwxr-x 2 jeff jeff 4096 Dec 13 17:14 meson-logs
drwxrwxr-x 2 jeff jeff 4096 Dec 13 17:05 meson-private
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is getting old now but in case someone runs into this again, I think an answer is still needed.

If the problem did not go away after correcting the build path as replied by [waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) then meson cannot find the run-time dependency to gtksourceview-4 to resolve calls into the library.

For the build to proceed you need to install the development version of the package:

`sudo apt install libgtksourceview-4-dev`

Before running this you might want to check if you have the ubuntu package installed at the system level with:

`sudo apt list | grep libgtksourceview-4`

The output will be self-explanatory. If not installed then you will have to do the two installs either on separate command line entries or on the same:

`sudo apt install libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-dev`

At the time of this writing, libgtksourceview-4-0 is the latest [Ubuntu package for amd64 architecture](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=GtkSourceView-4).

If you are curious as to what this package does, the following will give you a quick summary:

`apt show libgtksourceview-4-0`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69257467/1585486) will give you more hints for the errors you can see while you are doing running meson to build software due to lack of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions (and we'd rather see what you actually did, instead of what you were told to do) say to:

```
$ mkdir build
```

But, you've told `meson` to use

```
Build dir: /home/jeff/Programs/gtksourceview-4.4.0/biuild
```

"`build`" != "`biuild`"

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question, but the problem has not gone away!